# If I send everything to index.php would that affect ajax calls?

Tags: php, ajax, friendly-url

I have this in `.httaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

So everything goes to `index.php` but how to deal with ajax calls like this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "includes/php/dostuff.php",
    data: {"somvar": 5, "someothervar": 10}
})
```

Plus can I be 100% positive the `.httaccess` is really messing only with `.php` files the way I have it now?

Comment: Yes, ajax calls are no different from other http requests. Plus - no, the rewrite rule redirects **all** requests to index.php unless there are files or directories with exact name.

Comment: @AlexBlex How can I do to accomplish what I want? I was trying to use the routing feature from Laravel but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: How do I  know what you want?

Comment: You can exclude files or entire directories from being redirected to index by adding more conditions (e.g `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/includes/` or whatever your dir/file is). For more info read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html